# Work with Frameworks in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm following [this steps](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-framework-creation/) and works perfect, but i need something additional.

Each time when i do any change, is necessary remove the `.framework` file from parent project and go to framework project and generate a build again and drag and drop into the parent project `AGAIN`.

> It's possible make a reference in where only need run the `framework` project to see the changes in the parent project without need follow all this steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your framework in your framework project , right click on the .framework file in build folder , show in finder , drag it to your parent project , in the window that opens **uncheck** the "copy items ... " option. 
This will create a reference to your framework build file and not a copy.

Comment: not work for me, because when `uncheck` the `copy items` option. i can't access to my public classes in the framework

Comment: You need to build your parent project so the changes will update

Comment: Not works, say no such module `myframework` in the `import` line

Comment: Go to "Build phases" -> "Link binary with libraries" in your parent project and make sure your framework is there , if not then add it.